# Problem with Mysql result set, if there is 0 row on main query produce result from sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that checks the value of some case from DB and finds the rank in witch that value resides in table `BOD`:

```
        SELECT DISTINCT bod_bod, (SELECT REPLACE(predf_VPS,'.','') as vps FROM PREDMETIFView WHERE
     predf_nas_br=?) as vps_baza FROM BOD WHERE (SELECT REPLACE(predf_VPS,'.','') as vps
 FROM PREDMETIFView WHERE predf_nas_br=?) BETWEEN bod_od AND bod_do ORDER BY bod_bod ASC
                  LIMIT 1
```

Table BOD is:

```
| bod_id | bod_od    | bod_do    | bod_bod | bod_dodan           |
| ------ | --------- | --------- | ------- | ------------------- |
| 0      | 0.00      | 2500.00   | 25      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 1      | 2500.01   | 5000.00   | 50      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 2      | 5000.01   | 10000.00  | 75      | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 3      | 10000.01  | 100000.00 | 100     | 2020-04-10 13:06:53 |
| 4      | 100000.01 | 250000.00 | 250     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 5      | 250000.01 | 500000.00 | 500     | 2020-04-08 23:04:30 |
```

Current SQL for the sub-query value `11899` from `PREDMETIFView` table select gives me result:

```
bod_bod     vps_baza    
100     11899
```

because number `11899` is between `10000.01` and `100000.00`.

I later do some calculations with that number in PHP.

**But here is the problem:**
When the number is bigger then 500000.00, result set from query is 0 rows (because there is no rank that matches). But I still need that number `vps_baza` to do calculations in PHP.

So is there a way to say if there is no ranked matches that it still produces one result row (without altering table BOD) of for example for  `vps_baza 511899` value:

```
bod_bod     vps_baza    
null    511899
```

MySQL version is 5.6

I have made an [DBfiddle:](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j4WKWXev4cS6LB7x4KRqaT/0)

If you change value on line `98` from `511899` to for example `899`, i get the row, but bigger values then `500000` it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left join`:

```
select x.vps_baza, . . .
from (select 11899 as vps_baza) x left join
     bods b
     on x.vps.baza between b.bod_od and b.bod_do;
```

Note:  This answer is based on your question and sample data.  It is quite unclear to me what the *query* has to do with either of those.

Comment: Sorry if something is unclear, I have made DBfiddle in mid-time and edited the question. On first glance of this answer not sure I understand how this work, I will try now to make it work on my case.